# Reasoning behind deleting a question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This question was posted recently on the main site:

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/140379/boss-asking-for-proof-for-missing-interview

It was deleted minutes within getting posted. It managed to record two answers. However, it was deleted by one of the site [admins](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/61096/mister-positive).

I understand, users with enough privilege can vote to, and moderators can right-away delete a post. I was not able to determine the reason why the post was deleted.

Is it possible to know the reason why it was deleted? To make it clear, I am  only interested in knowing the objective reason (violating the site on-topic rules etc.) it was chosen to be deleted.

This will help me in understanding what kind of questions are and are not good candidates on the site.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how were you able to see that Mister Positive deleted the post? I thought only 10k+ users could see that.

Comment: @DavidK I posted an answer to the original question, and I was midway editing the answer. I also had access to the question URL.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330909/is-it-appropriate-for-a-site-admin-to-curtail-requested-information-from-a-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible, but it **was for good reason**.  That is all I feel is appropriate to say at the moment.